# Dominating function for infinite fn

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I am trying to find a dominating function $g(x)$ for the series of functions $\{f_n\}$ 
$$f_n = \frac{x~e^{-x/n}}{n^2}$$
The integral of the function $f_n$ I believe is a point mass of $1$ at $0$ when $n \rightarrow \inf$, But the trouble is how to a find a dominating function which can always be greater then $f_n$ and is finitely integrable, for all $n$, since $f_n$ keeps growing in height and moving toward $0$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note this is a function that I have made up to help me understand the application of Lebesgue's Dominating convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your functions become flatter for $n \to \infty$. But since $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx = 1$ independent of $n$, and $f_n \to 0$ uniformly, there cannot be an integrable dominating function.

If there were an integrable dominating function, the integrals of $f_n$ would converge to the integral of the pointwise limit, which is $0$.

You would get a peak marching towards $0$ for $g_n(x) = n^2xe^{-nx}$, but again, since the integral is independent of $n$, and $g_n \to 0$ pointwise, there cannot be an integrable dominating function.

Comment: Do you think there is anyway I can make use of the DCT to solve the problem, as you suggested $g_n(x) = n^2xe^{-nx}$

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you want to solve. If you have a sequence of functions converging (in the sense of distributions) to a point mass, the dominated convergence theorem _cannot_ be applicable (on the entire space), since the integrals converge to $1$, but the functions converge to $0$ pointwise (almost everywhere).

Comment: Thanks, I am asked to solve a problem similar to this one using dominated convergence, so I suppose I should use it on the pointwise convergent space only.

Comment: How similar? If you ask about the actual problem, we might be able to give useful hints.

Comment: Okay, I suppose you have $a > 0$ for the second. That is a case for the DCT, for all sufficiently large $n$, you have $a > \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, which allows you to find a dominating function. For the first, a substitution $y = nx$ gets you a long way to the target.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give your suggestions a go.